# Error while using iPython for executing a python script

Tags: python, django, ipython

I am using iPython 5.5.0, when i run my script which takes input for input.csv I get the following error:

In [1]: %run "C:\myrootFolder\pythoncode\testfile.py input.csv"

**ERROR:root:File** `u'In [1]: %run "C:\myrootFolder\pythoncode\testfile.py input.csv.py' not found.

Same way I am unable to execute..  %run "C:\Python27\Scripts\mysite\manage.py runserver"

Similar error occurs, What am I doing wrong.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue it should be 
%run "C:\myrootFolder\pythoncode\testfile.py" \input.csv